# is $2(\pi)i$ the same as $4(\pi)i$?

Tags: group-theory

I know $2\pi$ is the same angle as $4\pi$ but when they are both multiplied by i are they still the same?
I am trying to show that the set $μ_n= U n>=1 μ_n$ is a group under multiplication and I'm trying to figure out what the identity element is and  how to show it is invertible.

my thoughts so far is that $μ_1$ is the identity element, I'm still not sure what you can do to an element to invert it though.

Comment: Please use MathJax to write the math symbols. What is "mieu" ? Do you mean something like $\mu$ ?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial for MathJax.

Comment: $2\pi \approx 6.283$ is not the same as $4\pi\approx 12.566$ as numbers but might be seen as equivalent angles

Comment: “I know that $2\pi i$ is the same as $4\pi i$ ....” That is your first mistake.

Comment: Have a look for example to Fig. 5 page 11 of this article https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8121/aad8c6/pdf

Comment: What does $\mu_n$ represent?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

Since $e^{2\pi i}=1$, $e^{4\pi i}=1$. This doesn't mean the exponents are equal; it means complex-valued logarithms are multi-valued. From a group-theory perspective, it's like arguing a group of identity $E$ satisfying $E^1=E^2$ implies $1=2$.

Comment: Or, in other words, since the question has a "group theory" tag: The group homomorphism $\exp \colon \mathbb C \to \mathbb C^*$, $z \mapsto \exp(z)$ has a non-trivial kernel, which is indeed equal to $2\pi i \mathbb Z$. This means that $\exp(z + 2 \pi i k) = \exp(z)$ for any $k \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: does this mean that  μ_1 is the identity element for this group?

Answer (score 2):

$2 \pi \neq 4 \pi$, exactly because $2 \neq 4$. But some common functions are $2 \pi$-periodic (meaning their output is unchanged when a multiple of $2 \pi$ is added to the input), among them $\cos$, $\sin$ and the function I think you should be looking at here, as it satisfies $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$ for $x \in \mathbb R$.